# PhpStorm GIT custom automation

Tags: git, ide, phpstorm

I often use a git command like this in the PhpStorm console:

```
git add --all && git commit -m "fix the config publishing" && \
git tag -a v1.0.4 -m "fix the config publishing" && git push
```

I'd like to make it more convenient so that it would be a button opening a popup with 2 inputs: comment and tag. The corresponding parts of the command from above would be populated from the popup's inputs and then the command would be executed.

Do you guys know if this is possible in PhpStorm?

I know PhpStorm offers some git GUI, but it doesn't seem usable to me. Multiple complex dialog etc, whereas I only want to push all the changes assigning a tag, that's why the custom popup needed.

Comment: You may do this as ordinary bash/whatever script (that will ask for the info and assemble & run the final command) and then just run it using External Tools functionality (for example).

Comment: @lazyone yeah, I'm curious if something like that is possible using the ps means

Comment: Commit is `⌘+K`, Push is `⌘+⇧+K`.  Tagging has no hot key by default, but you can add it. It may be a bit more key strokes, but it give you greater control.

Comment: @Sergey Have a look at External Tools -- it supports macro fields, one of which can be user input -- here is official How To/Manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can achieve a similar convenient use case even without the use of "External tool" in your IDE, but simply through a script.

If that script is called `git-xxx` (for instance `git-actp`, for add-commit-tag and push), it can be a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tag=$1
shift
comment="$@"
git add --all
git commit -m "${comment}"
git tag -a ${tag} -m "${comment}"
git push
```

If that script is anywhere in your $PATH or %PATH% (it works on Windows too), you can call it with:

```
git actp v1.4.0 my comment with multiple words
```

No need to fill out fields.